# Kubuntu installation disk problem

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, kubuntu

WIN10. I've done all necessary changes on UEFI, I've also created a 25GB partition. When I try to install Kubuntu 17.10.1, I get up to the network stage, then it says that I only have 7.8GB which is the size of the usb and it won't let me get to the next stage where I actually select the partition.

This is the installation window. I can't get past the Wireless Tab. There's a pop-up window with the aforementioned error message.

[image]

Comment: Turns out I was still on Raid mode instead of AHCI.